# org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a `spring mvc` project. Sometimes while starting my `SpringBoot` application I am getting following error.

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:

The detail logs is mention below:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
```

Comment: Hi how you manage to solve this?

Comment: Ian Lim@ Just replace the pom.xml i.e delete it and paste it again. It works for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this in your pom.xml :)

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```