# java.lang.ClassCastException deploying CAS 5.3.3 Maven Overlay WAR on Wildfly 10

Tags: spring-boot, cas, wildfly-10

I'm deploying CAS 5.3.3 on Wildfly 10, using a Maven Overlay as specified in https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Maven-Overlay-Installation.html and using the project template at: https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/tree/5.3

After deploying to Wildfly 10, deploy fails with the following exception:

```
09:02:06,982 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cas: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cas: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
```

The problem may be related to Spring Boot Maven configuration. However, I have tried these solutions, but they are not working:

- [Spring Boot Websockets in Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792121/spring-boot-websockets-in-wildfly)
- [WildFly 10 Spring Boot war Deployment Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030771/wildfly-10-spring-boot-war-deployment-error)
- [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510605/org-apache-tomcat-websocket-wswebsocketcontainer-cannot-be-cast-to-io-undertow-w)

It may be related also to:

https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!topic/cas-user/Buzbh5XpnlI
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.14.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Edit: This is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">    
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
<artifactId>cas-overlay</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.rimerosolutions.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wrapper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <verifyDownload>true</verifyDownload>
                <checksumAlgorithm>MD5</checksumAlgorithm>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
                <executable>${isExecutable}</executable>
                <layout>WAR</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>



        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>cas</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
                <archive>
                    <compress>false</compress>
                    <manifestFile>${manifestFileToUse}</manifestFile>
                </archive>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>cas</finalName>
</build>

<properties>
    <cas.version>5.3.3</cas.version>
    <springboot.version>1.5.14.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    <!-- app.server could be -jetty, -undertow, -tomcat, or blank if you plan to provide appserver -->
    <!-- No ponemos ninguno, para desplegar en WildFly 10 -->
    <app.server></app.server>

    <mainClassName>org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher</mainClassName>
    <isExecutable>false</isExecutable>
    <manifestFileToUse>${project.build.directory}/war/work/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-webapp${app.server}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFileToUse>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>default</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
             <!--
            ...Additional dependencies may be placed here...
            -->
            <!--
            For Wildfly deployment
             -->        

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
             </dependency>               



        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>exec</id>
        <properties>
            <mainClassName>org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication</mainClassName>
            <isExecutable>true</isExecutable>
            <manifestFileToUse></manifestFileToUse>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.3.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>echo</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <echos>
                            <echo>Executable profile to make the generated CAS web application executable.</echo>
                        </echos>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>bootiful</id>
        <properties>
            <app.server></app.server>
            <isExecutable>false</isExecutable>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>pgp</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.s4u.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pgpverify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <pgpKeyServer>hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net</pgpKeyServer>
                        <pgpKeysCachePath>${settings.localRepository}/pgpkeys-cache</pgpKeysCachePath>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                        <verifyPomFiles>true</verifyPomFiles>
                        <failNoSignature>false</failNoSignature>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Can you provide your `pom.xml`? Have you replaced elements `<app.server>-tomcat</app.server>` to `<app.server></app.server>`? You are not deploying cas on tomcat so these elements should not be present.

Comment: Thanks, that was the fist thing I tried, I unsetted app.server. I have edited the question adding the pom.xml

Comment: I can still see in your `pom` `<app.server>-tomcat</app.server>` under `properties` entry. Can you also remove it please? Ignore my comment if you have already done it.

Comment: I have deleted -tomcat in bootiful profile, however I'm using the default profile, so it has no effect.

Comment: One last thing. Try the workaround proposed in [this thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6166) if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried that workaround with the same result, same exception.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I have solved it.

The CAS War overlay was loading two jars I couldn't exclude marking their dependencies as provided. The problem is that these jars came from the CAS overlay, it were copied into WEB-INF/lib of the generated war.

- tomcat-embed-websocket-*.jar -> java.lang.ClassCastException
- WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-*.jar -> Logging related exception

So I excluded them from the generated jar, using excludes.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

This is the final POM, which deploys correctly on Wildfly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">    
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
<artifactId>cas-overlay</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>    
<build>
    <plugins>           
        <!-- 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.rimerosolutions.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wrapper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <verifyDownload>true</verifyDownload>
                <checksumAlgorithm>MD5</checksumAlgorithm>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
                <executable>${isExecutable}</executable>
                <layout>WAR</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
         -->             

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>cas</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
                <archive>
                    <compress>false</compress>
                    <manifestFile>${manifestFileToUse}</manifestFile>
                </archive>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- Exclude these jars from the generated WAR:                                 
                             -->
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-*.jar</exclude>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-*.jar</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>                
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>cas</finalName>
</build>

<properties>
    <cas.version>5.3.3</cas.version>
    <springboot.version>1.5.14.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    <!-- app.server could be -jetty, -undertow, -tomcat, or blank if you plan to provide appserver -->        
    <app.server></app.server>

    <mainClassName>org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher</mainClassName>       
    <isExecutable>false</isExecutable>
    <manifestFileToUse>${project.build.directory}/war/work/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-webapp${app.server}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFileToUse>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- Corporate repositories -->

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--
      ...Additional dependencies may be placed here...
      -->                
 </dependencies>    
 </project>
```